# Automated testing for B2C custom policies

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, testcafe, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, mailinator

I am in search of a feasible option to automate the functional testing of B2C custom policies such as sign-in, sign up, profile edit, and forgot username.

I have been reviewing testcafe scripts and be able to perform a POC for the sign-in policy however developing a script for sign-up, profile edit (email) appears to be not possible with testcafe as the policy triggers the verification code that needs to be keyed into the B2C card.

Any insights on how to achieve/implement this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! SO is a portal for "code issues", you are asking for "which technology". What technologies have you found? On which basement you will base your decision?

Comment: import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button');
});

Comment: Please share more details about your scenario. What authorization system do use? What difficulties do you have implementing your scenario in TestCafe? Please prepare a sample that demonstrates the issue.